# Authenticate and connect with third party from Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, api

I need to get the following done, but am stuck on how to get this done:

User has UserID from the third party stored in Wordpress and need to make a call to the third party api like:
`https://thirdapi.com/authenticate.svc?user_id=12345`

The result will be: `"Token: Generated-Token"`

and need to make another call like so: `https://thirdapi.com/SSO.htm?token=Generated-Token`

but this is only used as Single Sign-On.

I would like to make the first call when a button is pressed. And also make the second call with the generated-token after the same button is pressed.

Another way I think would be is:

Store it in a cookie: User is logged in to Wordpress and connects to the third api and stores the token in a cookie, so it will know the user is authenticated? How would I do this?

What is the best way to make multiple API calls on a page?

For example:

- Make API call (1) and get the result for userID(1).
- Make API call (2) and get the result for userID(2).
- Make API call (3) and get the result for userID(3).

And show all results together. Also I can make 1 call per second.

Hope someone can help!

Thanks!

Comment: Try with `wp_remote_post` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post

Comment: @ArshidKV response can serve to get the first token, you can put it into a variable like $token = [response from wp_remote_post] and then on the click event of the button something like functiontocallapi('<?php echo $token  ?>') its not a pretty solution though. the functiontocallapi just need to do the ajax call using the token

Comment: @duatis thanks! Will have a look in to it. Also any idea how to do it using a cookie? And will this also be the solution to make multiple calls the same time?

Comment: within the **functiontocallapi** you can perform all the request that you need and handle them.